# Camera pose estimation using opencv C++, SolvePnP function

Tags: computer-vision, opencv

I am trying to measure the pose of a camera and I have done the following.

1. Mark world 3-D(Assuming z=0, since it is flat) points on corners of a square on a flat surface and assume a world coordinate system.(in cms)

Have taken the top left corner of the square as my origin and given the world points in the following order(x,y)or(col,row):
(0,0),(12.8,0),(12.8,12.8),(0,12.8)   - in cms

2. Detect those points in my image.(in pixels)
   The image points and world points are in the same order.
3. I have calibrated my camera for **intrinsic matrix** and **distortion coefficients**.
4. I use **SolvePnP** function to get rvec and tvec.
5. I use **Rodrigues** function to get rotation matrix.
6. To check if rvec and tvec is correct, I project back the 3-D points(z=0) using **ProjectPoints** into the image plane and I get the points correctly on my image with an error of 3 pixels on X- axis.
7. Now I go ahead and calculate my camera position in the world frame using the formula:

**cam_worl_pos = - inverse(R) * tvec**. (This formula I have verified in many blogs and also this makes sense)

8. But my **cam_worl_pos** x,y, and z in cms do not seem to be correct.

My doubt is, if I am able to project back the 3-D world point to image plane using rvec and tvec with (**3 pixel error on X-axis and almost no error on Y axis, hope it is not too bad**), then why am I not getting the camera position in world frame right.

Also, I have a doubt on SolvPnP rvec and tvec solution, they might be one of the multiple solutions, but not the one which I want.

How do I get the right rvec and tvec from SolvPnp or any other suggestions to get rvec and tvec would also be helpful.

**EDITS** :

**Image Size** - 720(row) * 1280(col)

**camera parameters**

```
cameraMatrix_Front=[908.65   0     642.88
                     0     909.28   364.95
                     0        0        1]

distCoeffs_Front=[-0.4589, 0.09462, -1.46*10^-3, 1.23*10^-3]
```

**OpenCV C++ code**:

```
vector<Point3f> front_object_pts;
Mat rvec_front;
Mat tvec_front;
Mat rotation_front;
Mat world_position_front_cam;


//Fill front object points(x-y-z order in cms)
//It is square of side 12.8cms on Z=0 plane
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(12.8, 0, 0));
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(12.8,12.8,0));
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(0, 12.8, 0));


//Corresponding Image points detected in the same order as object points
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[0]);
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[1]);
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[2]);
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[3]);

//Detected points in image matching the 3-D points in the same order
//(467,368)
//(512,369)
//(456,417)
//(391,416)

//Get rvec and tvec using Solve PnP
solvePnP(front_object_pts, front_image_pts, cameraMatrix_Front,
         Mat(4,1,CV_64FC1,Scalar(0)), rvec_front, tvec_front, false, CV_ITERATIVE);

//Output of SolvePnP
//tvec=[-26.951,0.6041,134.72]  (3 x 1 matrix)
//rvec=[-1.0053,0.6691,0.3752]  (3 x 1 matrix)


//Check rvec and tvec is correct or not by projecting the 3-D object points to image
vector<Point2f>check_front_image_pts
projectPoints(front_object_pts, rvec_front, tvec_front, 
             cameraMatrix_Front, distCoeffs_Front, check_front_image_pts);


//Here to note that I have made **distCoefficents**, 
//a 0 vector since my   image points are detected after radial distortion is removed

//Get rotation matrix
Rodrigues(rvec_front, rotation_front);

//Get rotation matrix inverse
Mat rotation_inverse;
transpose(rotation_front, rotation_inverse);

//Get camera position in world cordinates
world_position_front_cam = -rotation_inverse * tvec_front;
```

> //Actual location of camera(Measured manually)
>
> X=47cm
>
> Y=18cm
>
> Z=25cm
>
> //Obtained location
>
> X=110cm
>
> Y=71cm
>
> Z=-40cm

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Nithin. As it stands, this is a question more about OpenCV than about robotic systems. I saw that you started an identical question, which I'm assuming you did because you're frustrated at having received no response here. As this question is about *software trouble* you're having, and because you're not getting answers quickly here, I'm going to migrate this question to [so].

Comment: @Chuck Thank You Chuck. Hope I find some solution.