# solvePnP results differ too much from expected results (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, pose-estimation, opencv-solvepnp

I have a car with a camera, an imu and a gps on top of it. The camera takes pictures while driving around. The pictures and the gps coordinates are synchronized. Now, I am trying to get the camera pose from the pictures (relative to the imu), but `solvePnP` does not end up with an extrinsic camera calibration that is even similar to my expected results.

For more background: I am using Python (3.6.8) with OpenCV 4.0.0.

The following data I know:

1. I have 8 markers and their exact positions in world coordinates.
2. I have the trajectory of the imu in world coordinates.
3. I have pixel coordinates of the markers for several pictures (6576 x 4384 px).
4. I have the intrinsic camera calibration.

```py
In [4]: image_points
Out[4]:
array([[1911., 2115.],
       [2443., 2631.],
       [1427., 2570.],
       [1409., 2271.],
       [1396., 1912.],
       [1549., 1770.],
       [2247., 1787.],
       [2606., 1794.]], dtype=float32)

In [5]: world_points
Out[5]: 
array([[-1.5156984e+00, -1.3494657e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
       [-2.9987667e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
       [-9.3132257e-10,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
       [ 0.0000000e+00, -8.5239327e-01,  0.0000000e+00],
       [-1.5532847e-02, -1.8538033e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
       [-5.0486135e-01, -2.2495930e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
       [-2.5055323e+00, -2.2484162e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
       [-3.4857810e+00, -2.2520051e+00,  0.0000000e+00]], dtype=float32)

In [6]: cameraMatrix
Out[6]: 
matrix([[ 2.81923164e+03, -1.36877792e+00,  3.26989822e+03],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  2.81857995e+03,  2.24198230e+03],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])

In [7]: distCoeffs
Out[7]: array([ 0.0278163 , -0.01819595, -0.01031101, -0.0023199 , -0.02813449])
```

Currently, my process consists of:

1. I convert all world coordinates into a local marker coordinate
   system so that the z-coordinate of all markers is 0 (see Out[4] in the code example). At first, I
   tried it without this step but I read a lot of tutorials and it
   seems that the calibration somehow assumes this, but I am not sure. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.
2. I use `solvePnP` to get `rvec` and `tvec`.
3. I apply `cv2.Rogrigues(rvec)` to get the `rotationMatrix`
4. Then, the camera position in marker coordinates is calculated by `camPos = -np.matrix(rotationMatrix).T * np.matrix(tvec)`

After that, I compare the distance between imu and estimated camera position and it ends up to be something around 1m, but not even consistently. These are the results for 5 sample images.

```py
array([[0.65556006],
       [1.19668318],
       [1.37138227],
       [0.64020471],
       [0.55105675]])
```

However, the distance between imu and camera should be pretty exactly 2.4m (manually measured) and not change at all (since both are fixed at the top of the car).

**Is it possible that solvePnP outputs wrong results or am I doing mistakes somewhere else in my process?**

*Similar question but with no answers would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467927/camera-pose-estimation-using-opencv-c-solvepnp-function).*

Comment: Really no one? Do I need to provide more? Complete source code?

Comment: Pictures and your code will better help to understand the issue. btw the world points seems to be wrong , how did you calculate it ?